# Target first element inside its parent

Tags: jquery, list

I'm having trouble targeting the first element inside a list item using :first.

```
<li data-id="321">
    <ul>
        <li data-id="380">
            <ul>
                <li data-id="385"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-id="382"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```js
$(".drop .position").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $targetID = $(".box-cont.active ").closest("li.box").data("id");
    $childrenArray = new Array();
    if ($target.find("ul:first").find("li").length > 0) {
        $target.find("ul:first").find("li").each(function() {
            $this = $(this);
            $childrenArray.push($this.data("id"));
        });
        alert($childrenArray);
    } else {
        alert("no children");
    }
```

I'm only trying to target the children of the first ul inside 321. Instead, I'm adding 380, 382, and 385 to the array when I only want to add 380 and 382.

Comment: None of the elements you reference (`.box-cont` or `li.box` etc) are present in your example HTML.

Comment: What `div`? I see no `div` in your example

Comment: It sounds like you just need `$target.find("ul:first > li").each(function()` (or even better: `map()`) although seeing a more complete sample of your HTML would confirm this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's gonna find all the li, indeed. What you want are direct descendants.
Either replace find by children or use `"ul:first>li"` as your jQuery selector